# Loading Particular UI Menu from Different Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, settings

How would you access the Options/Settings Menu from an in-game Pause Menu?

I understand loading the different scene on the button click, but the scene I load (via loadscene) opens with my Main Menu UI. I want to load the Options/Settings UI when I load the Main Menu scene. I think just loading the Main Menu scene, then deactivating the Main Menu UI gameObject and activating the Options/Settings UI gameObject would be sufficient, but it only loads the Main Menu UI on scene change.

Here is my code for the button click (for loading the Options/Settings Menu UI):

```
    public enum GameOverStates
    {
        Main,
        Store,
    };

    public GameOverStates currentState;

    public GameObject mainMenu;
    public GameObject storeMenu;


    void Update()
    {
        switch (currentState)
        {
            case GameOverStates.Store:

                mainMenu.SetActive(false);
                storeMenu.SetActive(true);

                break;
        }
    }


       // Switch to Store Menu
    public void OnStore()
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The fucking store");

        //Change menu state
        Loader.Load(Loader.Scene.MainMenu);
        currentState = GameOverStates.Store;

        ////Play sound effect
        SoundManager.PlaySound(SoundManager.Sound.ButtonClick);
    }
```

Thank for you any help :)

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use `DontDestroyOnLoad` to keep your main menu in any other scene. just call it on `Start` function and MainMenu object will be not destroyed by `SceneManager`. ([Read here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html))
2. Use `SceneManager.MergeScenes` to append two different scene on loading the new one. so it will keep your main menu and add your other scene to it. ([Read Here](http://SceneManager.MergeScenes))

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I ended up finding a workaround by instantiating the particular UI in the desired scene and just referencing it there. It seems to save on performance too, as I do not have to load another scene